# jquery clone does not create unique object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How do you clone a unique instance of a cloned list item?  The way I have it currently coded, always creates a duplicate of itself - for example, I clone a list item once, it creates one copy, then I clone the same list item again and it creates two copies.

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><button onclick='cloneit(this);'>Clone</button> List Item A</li>
    <li><button onclick='cloneit(this);'>Clone</button> List Item B</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function cloneit(thisone) {
    var parent = $(thisone).parent();
    $(parent).clone().appendTo(parent);
}
```

You can see the above at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57kx6u3j/

To duplicate the problem, click on **Clone** for *List Item A* and you'll see it cloned once, then click on the *same button* and you'll see it cloned twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are appending a cloned `li` to the same `li` because `this` refers to the button element.

Fix: http://jsfiddle.net/57kx6u3j/1/